# MIT OCW Intro to CS practice test 1?

Tags: python

The following code contains two semantic errors. Correct it so that it reads in integers until the user enters -1, and then prints the sum of the integers (8 points):

```
def getLines():

    inputs = []
    while True:
        line = raw_input('Enter a positive integer, -1 to quit: ')
        if line == -1:
            break
        inputs.append(line)

total = 0
for e in getLines():
total += e
print total
```

I'm guessing you need to replace `getLines()` in the `for-loop` with an actual list. The function must return the list `inputs`.

But inside the function's `while loop`, `if line == -1:` never returns True. How come?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I'm guessing you need to replace "getLines()" in the for-loop with an actual list. The function must return the list "inputs".

Exactly.

---

> But inside the function's while loop, "if line == -1:" never returns True. How come?

Try this on the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> '-1' == -1
False
```

Except in a very limited set of special cases (e.g., `int` and `float`), values of different types are never equal.

Now look up what [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns:

> … The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

So, when you type `-1`, that `raw_input` will return the string `'-1'`.

You could fix this by checking against the string `'-1'` instead of the number `-1`. But is that what you want? If someone types, say, `-1` with a space, should that count as quitting? If so, you might want to call `line.strip()`.

---

But there's actually a *third* error here… and the fact that they only claim 2 errors makes me think they want you to solve the two together.

`inputs` is going to be a list of strings. You can add those all together, but all that's going to do is concatenate them into one big string, not add them as numbers. So really, you probably need to convert each string into an integer, e.g.:

```
try:
    number = int(line)
except ValueError:
    print 'I said a positive integer, does %s look like an integer?' % (line,)
    continue
```

And if you do that, the previous problem magically goes away, because `number == -1` will be true.

Of course you also need to figure out how to deal with the user typing `0` or `-32` or something else that is a valid `int` but neither a positive integer nor `-1`. Don't you just love edge cases?